# Adding a Subquery to a Query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a query that works very well.  Let me start with it:

**Edit:**  The SQL has been updated.  I get `0` in every row.

```
   SELECT i.item, i.user_id, u.username,
        (COALESCE(r.ratetotal, 0)) AS total,
        (COALESCE(c.commtotal, 0)) AS comments,
        (COALESCE(r.rateav, '50%')) AS rate,
        (COALESCE(x.wasRated, '0')) AS wasRated
        FROM items AS i
        LEFT JOIN master_cat AS c
            ON (c.cat_id = i.cat_id)
        LEFT JOIN users AS u 
        ON u.user_id = i.user_id    
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT item_id, 
            COUNT(item_id) AS ratetotal, 
            AVG(rating) AS rateav 
            FROM ratings GROUP BY item_id) AS r 
        ON r.item_id = i.item_id
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT item_id, 
            COUNT(item_id) AS commtotal 
            FROM reviews GROUP BY item_id) AS c
        ON c.item_id = i.item_id
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT xu.user_id, ra.item_id, '1' AS wasRated
            FROM users AS xu
            LEFT JOIN ratings AS ra
                ON ra.user_id = xu.user_id
            WHERE xu.user_id = '1') AS x 
         ON x.user_id = u.user_id
              AND x.item_id = r.item_id
        WHERE c.category = 'Movies' 
        ORDER by i.item ASC;
```

I need to add one more function to it, where you see `AS x`

Basically, there are three tables here that are important.  `items`, `reviews` and `ratings`.  In the top portion you see there are subqueries that are taking statistics such as averages and totals for each item.

I need a final query that is tied to `user_id`, `item_id` and `rate_id` (in `ratings`).  In the end result, where it list each item and the stats with it, I want one more column, a simple true or false if logged in user has rated it.  So I need something like this:

```
SELECT ???
FROM ratings AS r
WHERE r.user_id = '{$user_id}'
```

(`user_id` of logged in user is passed in from PHP.`)

How can I make a subquery that gives me that last bit of info, but puts it in each row of items in the parent query?

Comment: You'll probably get more responses if you post the SQL DDL for your tables, and some SQL INSERT statements, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the parent query.

```
, coalesce(x.WasRated, 'false') as WasRated
```

Your x subquery is:

```
(select users.user_id
 , ratings.item_id
, 'true' WasRated
from users join ratings on user.user_id = ratings.user_id
where users.user_id = the one for the logged in user
) x on x.user_id = users.user_id
and x.item_id = ratings.item_id
```

or something like it.

Comment: I have updated my code based on your submission and also included result.  Any thoughts?

Comment: My suggestion was to do an inner join from users to ratings in the subquery.  You have  a left join.  My intent was that the subquery would return 'true' if the user rated an item.  The coalesce function in the main query would change that to false if he didn't.  Putting a left join in the subquery will make it return true for every user.

Comment: I just changed it to an inner join and made some very tiny tweaks and got it working!  Marked correct, thanks!